# Grab array of div in JS based on parent id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with 3 columns in it. In each column are several divs with the same class name, like so.

```
<div id="column1">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>

<div id="column2">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>

<div id="column3">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"></div>  
</div>
```

I want to be able to grab each child div under each column and store them into 3 separate arrays in JS. So in pseudo-code

```
var children1 = all children of #column1 with the class .child,
children 2 = all children of #column2 with the class .child,
children 2 = all children of #column2 with the class .child;
```

I need to be able to apply a background color to the .child divs based on which column they are in. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you not just give the children of the different columns, different classes and then achieve the change of the background color through CSS?

Comment: for the arrays, you can just use [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children). For the background color, you can just use CSS

Comment: @Geshode, yeah I guess I could if this doesn't pan out. Good point!

Comment: @Hamms I have to use jQuery for the background color because it's being pulled in through PHP and only applied on hover. I wish I could use CSS for it, I really do. JS is not my forte.

Comment: `var col1Array = document.getElementById('column1').getElementsByClassName('child');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select as below

```
var children1 = document.getElementById('column1').getElementsByClassName('child');
```

Answer (score 1):

With [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object and [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

#### Example

```js
var children1 = document.querySelectorAll('#column1 > .child'),
  children2 = document.querySelectorAll('#column2 > .child'),
  children3 = document.querySelectorAll('#column3 > .child'),
  content1 = Array.from(children1, child => child.textContent);

console.log(content1);
```

```html
<div id="column1">
  <div class="child">Column 1a</div>
  <div class="child">Column 1b</div>
  <div class="child">Column 1c</div>
</div>

<div id="column2">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="column3">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```